# How to get All Child Category Product under Parent Category id in laravel

Tags: laravel, query-builder, eloquent-relationship

In categories table

> categories

| id | categoryName | parentId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Men's Fashion | NULL |
| 2 | T-Shirt | 1 |
| 3 | Pants | 1 |
| 4 | Shoes | 1 |

And another table is

> products

| id | productName | productCategoryId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2 |
| 2 | B | 3 |
| 3 | C | 4 |

And My Menu List is

- Men's Fashion

  - A
  - B
  - C

When i click "A" then i can show all "A" category product. That can i already solved.
But i can't show all products under "Men's Fashion". (In "Men's Fashion" here show "A", "B", and "C" subcategory product.) How can i solve this ?

Answer (score 2):

In product model you need to have a relation between product and category like this

```
public function category(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

so to get products for category 1 the query will be like

```
$products = Product::whereHas('category', function ($q) {
         $q->where('parentId', 1)
})->get();
```

Comment: thank you @ayman-elmalah, i can try but i can't get result.